# Google Maps API Circle Icons

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make a map using Google Maps API and the red dot icons (aka earthquake icons).

I have several locations and several magnitudes, since some of magnitudes are lower therefore it will not be very visible so the red dot icons only will apply to some locations.

```
var marker1;
var marker2
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    if (locations[i][3] > 5){
        alert("I am in");}  
        marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: getCircle(locations[i][3])
        }); 
    if(locations[i][3] < 5){
        marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        });
    }
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker1);
    }
  })(marker1, i)); 
}
```

The problem resides on marker1. Because if i try to limit the marker to locations where magnitude is higher than 5 it will not design a single icon and the alert will not even be trigger.

BUT if I remove the code of the marker1 from within the "if" statement (like the example), the alert is triggered and the icons appear on the map.

Marker 2 can be filtered with no problems.

Why is this working this way? I just simply move the "}" a few lines below. I cannot understand.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can only give the source code and the array of magnitudes, because the file and the webpage are on intranet.

Has i said, yes. I am sure there are values bigger than 5 :)

Comment: Hum maybe this getCircle(locations[i][3]) doesn't work for locations[i][3] > 5? I would like to test to be more helpful but this way i can only guess. Does it appear any error on the console?

Comment: No, because all icons are being draw without the "if" statement. Once the "if" statement tries to filter the icons which are meant to be red circle, none is drawn although there is in fact magnitudes higher and lower than 5. If I do a if/else with the "if" statement belonging to the BOUNCE icons and the else to the red circle the icons are selected properly, if the I try the inverse, none is draw.

Answer (score 1):

That code is very complicated, and the way it uses the two global `marker1` and `marker2` variables, it can't possibly do anything that you want it to do.

I'm not entirely clear what it is you *do* want the code to do, but can I show you a much cleaner way to code it that may be a step in the right direction?

```
for( var i = 0;  i < locations.length;  i++ ) {
    addMarker( locations[i] );
}

function addMarker( location ) {
    var lat = location[1], lng = location[2],
        magnitude = location[3], content = location[0];

    var options = {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ),
        map: map
    };

    if( magnitude > 5 ) {
        options.icon = getCircle( magnitude );
    }
    else {
        options.animation = google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE;
    }

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker( options );

    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent( content );
        infowindow.open( map, marker );
    });
}
```

Differences worth noting:

- No global `marker1` and `marker2` variables. Instead, every marker has its very own `marker` variable.
- A simple call to the `addMarker()` method creates the closure you need, instead of the complicated function-returning-a-function.
- Use of named variables for all those `locations[i][n]` properties to make it more readable.
- Handles the case where magnitude is exactly 5, which the original code skips. (Change the test from `> 5` to `>= 5` if needed.)
- Combined the two `google.maps.Marker()` calls to avoid a bit of repetition.

Hopefully that will make it easier to figure out what is going on and what you need to do.

Comment: I tried your code, it is in fact much cleaner.

Although the error persist (the "if" statement on the options magnitude > 5 for the red circle icon) IF i inverse the if statement (if now belongs to bounce on magnitude < 5) the selection goes well.

Some bug?